# Unity 5.3 with C# - Toggle Sound On/Off

Tags: unity, c#, unityscript, sound

*I'm working with Unity 5.3 with C# as code editor*

**These are what I have :**

I have 2 scenes in my project : `home` and `options`. I have `bg` object on both scenes. Both `bg` objects have `Audio Source` component, which contains same background music that `play on awake`. I don't use any codes for these background musics, I only click the `Add Component` button from Unity and add `Audio Source`.

**This is what I want :**

`Options` scene can toggle the background music on/off for all scenes. Therefore, there are `btnOn` and `btnOff` in `Options` scene.

**This is my code in Audio Manager.cs :**

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class AudioManager : MonoBehaviour {
    public Button btnOn;
    public Button btnOff;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        btnOn = GetComponent<Button>();
        btnOff = GetComponent<Button>();

        btnOn.onClick.AddListener(() => PlayAudio());
        btnOff.onClick.AddListener(() => StopAudio());
    }

    void PlayAudio()
    {
        AudioSource.volume = 0.5f;
    }

    void StopAudio()
    {
        AudioSource.volume = 0f;
    }
}
```

**This is the problem :**

I have this error : `An object reference is required to access non-static member UnityEngine.AudioSource.volume`. Maybe, this is because I don't write `public AudioSource audioSource` in my code. But, if I write this, I have to add another audio in `Get Component` box, and I will have double `Audio Source` in one scene. What should I do? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you that, you're trying to access a non-static variable ***volume*** with the class name ***AudioSource***, which is not possible. To access a non-static member, you neeed an *Instance* of the class.

Therefore, you have to define an Instance of the AudioSource class to access ***volume*** variable, and then assign it an AudioSource component either from Inspector or from code. Like this :

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class AudioManager : MonoBehaviour {
    public Button btnOn;
    public Button btnOff;

    public AudioSource audioSource; 

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        btnOn = GetComponent<Button>();
        btnOff = GetComponent<Button>();

        // Either use this, or assign the component from inspector
        audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>(); 

        btnOn.onClick.AddListener(() => PlayAudio());
        btnOff.onClick.AddListener(() => StopAudio());
    }

    void PlayAudio()
    {
        audioSource.volume = 0.5f;
    }

    void StopAudio()
    {
        audioSource.volume = 0f;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have explained in my question that, if I use `public AudioSource audioSource`, I have to add another bgm to `GetComponent`. So, I will have two `GetComponent`, is that okay to have two?

Comment: @GraceMichelle, I clearly didn't get what you meant by saying *I will have two GetComponent*, because *GetComponent* is just a generic method you can use as many times as you like.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing `AudioListener` with `AudioSource`. They're different things. There can be many audio sources in the scene but only one audio listener. Try using `AudioListener.volume` to set the volume instead.

You might also want to [pause](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioListener-pause.html) it.